# handle IPB xml-rpc api response

Tags: php, xml, xml-rpc, ipb

IPB Board provides a class (classXmlRpc) to access board features via a remote server. 
Sending a request seems easy to me, however I fail at processing the response I get.

I tried loading the response into SimpleXML but got a fatal error, so I did a var_dump, would have expected to see xml, instead I see something that doesn't look like xml...

Here's the [entire output](http://www.gaming-nexus.com/test.php)

Here's the request via the classXmlRpc:

```
$response   = $classXmlRpc->sendXmlRpc( "http://jdbartist.bplaced.net/forum/interface/board/index.php", "fetchStats", array( 'api_module' => 'ipb', 'api_key' => 'security_key' ) ) ;
```

And this is a small snippet of the output:

```
array(2) { 
    ["html attr"]=> array(1) { 
        ["lang"]=> string(2) "en" 
    }
    ["html"]=> &array(3) { 
        ["head"]=> array(5) { 
            ["title"]=> string(30) "Error - Gaming Nexus Community" 
            ["meta"]=> array(16) { 
                [0]=> string(0) "" 
                ["0 attr"]=> array(1) { 
                    ["charset"]=> string(5) "UTF-8" 
                }
                ["1 attr"]=> array(2) { 
                        ["http-equiv"]=> string(15) "X-UA-Compatible"
...
```

Basically, what is that and how can I access the data within those arrays?

Comment: I have the exact same problem, the issue is that its actually getting back the Invision Board error page HTML and not the actual API response. Im trying to figure it out and will post if I find a solution here.